# Join consult using "Web Controller 2 with actions, using Entity Framework"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a consult using the framework I mencioned before.

I've seen It's really easy to do basic consults, but I cannot do this.

I have a table called "Alumno" and I have other called "Historico". Every Alumno is in a "Grupo", I want to get all the Historicos using a "Grupo" as reference.

I have a foreignkey called "Grupo"
I need to use the "Grupo" to get the "Historico"  of some "Alumnos".

But I don't know how to join it.

Here's the ER diagram

Thanks, great day.

Comment: Okay angel we need more information here, your question is lacking the classes of "Practica" and "Grupo". Also it is vital that we see your DbContext Class . I also encourage you as a good practise whenever you are using a ForeingKey make sure the propery is Called  Id<YOURCLASS> for example: IdAlumno or AlumnoId both are correct, but its easier to read the code when you maintain certain order.

Comment: Hey there. I added the diagram. I'd be really grateful if you could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ, assuming you have the grupoId you want to get historicos from

```
var historicos = from grupo in db.Group
                 join alumno in db.Alumno
                 on grupo.IdGrupo equals alumno.IdGrupo
                 join practica in db.Alumno_Practica
                 on alumno.IdAlumno equals practica.IdAlumno
                 join historico in db.Historico
                 on practica.IdPractica equals historico.IdPractica
                 where grupo.IdGrupo == @yourIdGrupo
                 select historico
```

This is just a guide, replace the @ values with the data you need and execute it in your code.

Comment: Hello, I'm getting some error with your answer. The errors are in alumno, grupo, practica, but I do not know how to fix them. I think your answer is correct but it is not working propertly

Comment: Which is the error you're getting? Copy it here, I didn't tested the code myself, as I mentioned is just a guide, so only running it your side can be completed. If you copy the error here I might see what's wrong

Comment: it says "alumno" is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on the either side of 'equals'

Comment: I'll post a link with the image.

Comment: seems that needs to be swapped, instead of "alumno.IdGrupo equals grupo.IdGrupo" needs to be "grupo.IdGrupo equals alumno.IdGrupo" since the 1st component of the query is Grupo.

Comment: I've done it, an it fixed a lot, just one part has mistake but i did not know how to fix it

Comment: i posted the second pic

Comment: Seems that what isn't detected now is the clause where I set the evaluation with the corresponding IdGrupo, I edited the response, now that goes in the where clause

Comment: Now i have an error that says cannot convert bool  to int but grupo is int and the parameter is int

Comment: I saw it, check your code, in the image I saw that you have  grupo.IdGrupo = @yourIdGrupo, needs to be "==" not "=" since it's a conditional not a valur asignment

Comment: Sure, you're welcome, I'm glad I was able to guide you. Please mark my response as the correct one